# cloudflare not loading my website

Tags: cloudflare

Suddenly, I can't access any of website which is using cloudflare.

when I do a wget to my website it says

```
ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches
        requested host name `yoursite.com'.
```

but when I do `--no-check-certificate` the html is loaded.

my web server is still up and running, nothing wrong there. seems like the issue is with cloudflare I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: do you have SSL setup on the site? or did you force all request on cloudflare to load through ssl?

Comment: is there SSL configured on your origin server? I turned on Flexible SSL sometime back on some of my domains on cloudflare and it messed up. Try disabling flexible SSL or install SSL on your origin server.

Comment: you mean setup SSL on nginx? I already did it. I actually had it working with SSL but then eventually cancelled the pro plan because they announced free SSL. maybe that is the issue?

Comment: that  could most likely be the problem. Like I said, after enabling flexible ssl on a couple of my domains, I had similar issues. Turn off flexible ssl on cloudflare and you should be fine.

Comment: You can also just use a self-signed certificate on your server and  Full SSL.

Comment: Is security really needed or is SSL just a nice thing to have? In the former case, you should definitely **not** use CloudFlare's free SSL, as many sites use the same certificate via SNI (they don't have the private key of course), and the connection from CloudFlare to your server is not secured. Installing a self-signed certificate on your server won't help either—CloudFlare cannot verify it because it's self-signed. If you need **actual** security, the only viable option is to get an SSL certificate signed by a CA. If you need CloudFlare for other things too, you can use "Full SSL (strict)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you downgrade from a paid CloudFlare plan to the free version? The issuance of the new certificate on a free plan can take up to 24 hours or so.